# How to insert new lined order to existing order using QODBC?

Tags: insert, record, exists, insertion, qodbc

```
Array ( [0] => 120-1496395352 ) UPDATE SalesOrderLine SET SalesOrderLineItemRefListID='80000002-1496311427', SalesOrderLineQuantity =1, SalesOrderLineRate=200, SalesOrderLineItemRefFullName='Ipad', SalesOrderLineAmount=200, SalesOrderLinedesc='Ipad', CustomerRefListID='80000005-1496311377', RefNumber='9', TxnDate={d'2017-06-30'} WHERE SalesOrderLineTxnLineID='120-1496395352'

INSERT INTO SalesOrderLine ( SalesOrderLineItemRefListID, SalesOrderLineQuantity, SalesOrderLineRate, SalesOrderLineItemRefFullName, SalesOrderLineAmount, SalesOrderLinedesc, CustomerRefListID, RefNumber, TxnDate ) VALUES ( '80000004-1496311430', 2, 5, 'sandwich', 10, 'sandwich description sandwich', '80000005-1496311377', '9', {d'2017-06-30'} )
```

I want to insert the query to the same txnid but when I put txnid it say field not required in insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert SalesOrderLine item to an existing SalesOrder, then please refer below mentioned link for How to insert SalesOrderLine item to an existing SalesOrder:

[How to insert SalesOrderLine item to an existing SalesOrder](https://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/2843)

If you are still facing the issue, I kindly request you to please raise a support ticket to the QODBC Technical Support department from below mentioned link & provide requested information:

http://support.flexquarters.com/esupport/index.php?/Tickets/Submit

We may need the following information, I kindly request you to attach below listed files when replying to the ticket.

1) Screenshot of QODBC Setup Screen -- > About

2) Screenshot of the issue you’re facing.

Share Entire Log Files as an attachment in text format from

3) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review QODBC Messages

4) QODBC Setup Screen -- > Messages -- > Review SDK Messages